# Get value CSS from multiple same class name in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to Get value CSS from multiple same class name in jQuery?

That is, I have many elements that want to be entered into the database,

Each of these elements has different CSS values,

For example the CSS value of each element is 'background-image',

I want to take the value of each element and input into the database using Ajax request,

Question, how to take CSS value from each data on that element?

Use this simple Example

```js
$('.content').each(function() {
  $('.result').html('isi1: ' + $(this).css('width') + ' ==== isi2: ' + $(this).css('width'));
});
```

```css
span.content {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  background: #666;
}

span.isi1 {
  width: 100px;
}

span.isi2 {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id_1">
  <span class="content isi1">ISI1</span>
  <span class="content isi2">ISI2</span>
</div>

<p class="result"></p>
```

Edit on https://jsfiddle.net/FIERMANDT/b1pq3p3z/

**Edit 21 Jul 2020 VanilaJS version**

```js
/*for loop and getComputedStyle() method*/
var getEachCSSVal = document.querySelectorAll('.content');

for (var i = 0; i < getEachCSSVal.length; i++) {
  var cssVal = window.getComputedStyle(getEachCSSVal[i]).getPropertyValue('width');
  console.log(cssVal)
}
```

```css
span.content {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  background: #666;
}

span.isi1 {
  width: 100px;
}

span.isi2 {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="id_1">
  <span class="content isi1">ISI1</span>
  <span class="content isi2">ISI2</span>
</div>

<p class="result"></p>
```

Comment: you are already getting the value inside result container. What else do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Console

```js
$('.content').each(function(index){
console.log($(this).css('width'));
});
```

```css
span.content {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  background: #666;
}

span.isi1 {
  width: 100px;
}

span.isi2 {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id_1">
  <span class="content isi1">ISI1</span>
  <span class="content isi2">ISI2</span>
</div>
<p class="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

**The problem with your code is that you "overwrite" the value with last iteration from the each loop...**

`$(this)` is the actual element inside the loop.

See how the `each()` function works. in the callback you can get the `index` and then you kind of know where you are if you [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) html content to an element.

```js
$('.content').each(function(index){
$( ".result" ).append( "<div>isi"+index+": "+$(this).css('width')+"</div>" );
});
```

```css
span.content {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  background: #666;
}

span.isi1 {
  width: 100px;
}

span.isi2 {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id_1">
  <span class="content isi1">ISI1</span>
  <span class="content isi2">ISI2</span>
</div>

<p class="result"></p>
```

Comment: This does not answer my question, 
I want to take the CSS value from each of those elements

Comment: both, In the same class name :)....Do i have to use method for(), To get both values ​​dynamically

Comment: @Firmansyah which is both? you can get them all! So my question is which one(s) do you want? Do you want to compare the values from one element to the other?

Comment: I want to get the CSS value, From class 'isi1' and 'isi2'......
But whose class is executed is $('.content') not $('.isi1') or $('.isi2').....

Comment: @Firmansyah if you click on "Run code snippet" you see `isi0: 100px` and `isi1: 200px` which is the index (starting at 0) I can change that if you like. But that are 100% the values from isi1 and isi2

Comment: The problem with your code is that you overwrite the width() on the second each loop...

Comment: Thx for you help, It's Work :D, Very Awesome